# Japanese character encoding problem on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am encountering a problem concerning text-encoding on iPhone. I retrieve japanese characters from a sqlite database. So I get character like that ( their ASCII representation here : "& #25104;& #12395;& #12424;& #12427;" )

When I display these characters on a WebView, my japanese characters are well displayed. But when I try to display them on a UILabel, the ASCII representation is displayed rather than the japanese one.

I retrieve the text data from the database with the following function :

```
NSString *watchText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

If anyone has an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because what you have is not an "ASCII representation".  Those (`"&#25104;&#12395;&#12424;&#12427;"`) are known as XML or HTML character entity references.  As such, they only work if you parse them in an HTML context (like a web view).

What you need to do is either use a UIWebView for your labels, or parse the character entity references to turn them in to a normal NSString.